# How to let pool.starmap support infinite sequence multiprocess (for example infinite stream coming)

Tags: python, multiprocess

I made the very simple example and see whether starmap can concurrently call add_func and iter_func which yield new argument at the same time, But unfortunately, it doesn't work

```
from functools import partial
from itertools import repeat
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support
import time
def add_func(a, b):
    print(a,b)
    return a + b

def iter_func():
    i = 0
    while True:
        print("yeild")
        yield i,i+1
        i+=1
        time.sleep(1)
def main():
    with Pool() as pool:
        L = pool.starmap(add_func, iter_func())
        print(L)


freeze_support()
main()
```

Comment: You can try this code, it doesn't call add_func and iter_func at the same time

Comment: `for x in iter_func(): L = pool.apply(add_func, x)` - will work

Comment: Since starmap tries to chop the iterable into chunks - i could assume that it's imposible to use it with infinite generator

Comment: Yes , maybe the apply_async will work